# YUV/PCM Visualizer to measure Lip Sync

Tags: pcm, yuv

I have a two dump files of raw video and raw audio from an encoder and I want to be able to measure the "Lip-sync". Imagine a video of a hammer striking an anvil. I want to go frame by frame and see that when the hammer finally hits the anvil, there is a spike in amplitude on the audio track.

Because of the speed that everything happens at, I cannot merely listen to the audio, i need to see the waveform in time domain.

Are there any tools out there that will let me see both the video and audio?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be programming related.  If you were asking for how such a tool could be written, that'd be different, but this is akin to asking for a photo editing app.

Comment: I agree, it looks to me like this is really a question about "how to I validate A/V sync" which given some more context my be a programming question, but at this point is to general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are concerned about validating a decoder then generally from a validation perspective the goal is to check Audio and Video PTS values against a common real time clock.

Raw YUV and PCM files do not include timestamps. **If** you know the frame-rate and sample-rate you can use a raw yuv file viewer (I wrote my own) to figure out the time (from start of file) of a given frame in the video, and a tool like Audacity to figure out the time form start of file to a start of tone in the audio file. this still may not tell you the whole story since tools usually embed a delay between the audio and video in the ts/ps file. Or you can hook up ab OScope and go old school.